# Fetch Landscape Only PHAssets using PHFetchOptions

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I am able to successfully retrieve videos using the following function:

```
func getVideoAssets() {
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false) ]
    options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)

    videos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
    print(videos)
    prepareCollectionView()
}
```

However, I would like to get only LANDSCAPE videos as my app only supports landscape videos.
I have tried the following:

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(mediaType = %d) AND (pixelWidth > pixelHeight)", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
```

But I get a the following crash:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: pixelWidth > pixelHeight'

It looks like I cannot filter using that method. Is there another way to go about doing this? It seems as if the NSPredicate only accepts arguments and not comparing between 2 values in the PHAsset.

How can I go about retrieving only landscape videos using PHFetchOptions?

Comment: You could always filter `videos` into a new array based in checking the orientation.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah thats what I ended up doing anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with a solution that does not use NSPredicate but just filters the array of assets after it has been retrieved.
It worked fine for me, I was hoping to use NSPredicate but I'm satisfied.

Hopefully this helps someone else:

```
// get landscape only content
let unfilteredVideosArray = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
var filteredVideosArray : [PHAsset] = []
for i in 0..<unfilteredVideosArray.count {
    let video = unfilteredVideosArray.object(at: i)
    if video.pixelWidth > video.pixelHeight {
        filteredVideosArray.append(video)
    }
}

self.videos = filteredVideosArray
```